# I want to give unique id to component when using generic handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// ...
const AddUser = (props) => {
  // ...
  const submitEventHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(user);
    if (user.name.trim().length === 0 || user.age.trim().length === 0) {
      setIsValid(false);
    }
    if (+user.age < 1) {
      setIsValid(false);
    } else {
      setIsValid(true);

      setUserList((prev) => {
        return [...prev, user];
      });
      setUser(initialState);
    }
    console.log(user);
  };
  const changeEventHandler = (type, value) => {
    setUser((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [type]: value };
    });
  };
// ...
};

export default AddUser;
```

```
import Card from "./UI/Card";
import classes from "./UserList.module.css";

const UserList = (props) => {
  const userList = props.userList;
  return (
    <Card className={classes.users}>
      <ul>
        {userList.map((user) => {
          return (
            <li key={user.id}>
              {user.name} ({user.age} years old)
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

I want to give unique id to user state (key in `<li>`) when using map method
but I'm using generic handler (changeEventHandler in AddUser component)
so when I added id property in generic handler it'll be repeated whenever changeEvetHandler is triggered
what is the best way I can add unique id property when using generic handler?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, why would the same `id` value being store multiple times be an issue? You're setting state to `{ ...prev, [type]: value }`, so you wont end up with duplicates.

Comment: I think you have bigger problems if your user id is not unique, than the li key. I'd suggest ensuring your user ids are unique.